# [Symfony + Twig]

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I have base template (base.html.twig) with link to dynamically generated js:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('renderJs') }}"></script>
</script>
```

and Action which renders this JS:

```php
/**
     * @Route("/scripts.js",
     *  name="renderJs")
     */
    public function renderJsAction(Request $request)
    {
        return new Response(
            $this->renderView(
                "AcmeBundle:Default:renderJs.js.twig",
                array('foo' => 'bar')
            ),
            200,
            array('Content-Type' => 'text/javascript')
        );
    }
```

But I want render JS with the same Twig context as in base template (have the same variables in renderJs.js.twig as in base.html.twig).
Is that possible? Any ideas how to handle this problem?

Comment: is `renderJs.js.twig` extending `base.html.twig`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how everything's working (as I understand it):

1. base.html.twig renders, putting a URL to the renderJS action route into the source for the script tag
2. A users browser loads the generated page, and finds the URL for the renderJS action in a script tag and then makes another request to the server to get that.

So there's two requests in this case: the one to get the base.html.twig render, and then another to get script file the renderJS URL gives. By the time the server gets the second request, the context for the first is gone.

I can think of two options. Option 1 is to regenerate the context (ideally by having some class or method set up to do it in both places). That's good if you want to have a second request for the javascript file (like if it can be cached) and generating the context isn't very resource intensive.

Option 2 is to skip the need for the action and include the render.js.twig template in the base.html.twig template as inline javascript. That's probably only a good idea if the context is really expensive to create and the javascript is light and will never be cached (but it's probably better to let the file get cached as much as it can).

Let me know how they sound and how they might apply to you and I can dig in to more details.

Comment: Yup I've consider both options but I was wondering if it is another one.

Comment: 1) Regenerating context probably will took too much time so second option will be better, but:
2) there are many lines of scripts, it will be working this way, but not looks good in source code preview

Comment: What about using something like redis or memcached? As long as everything's loaded (I'm thinking of lazy loaded in Doctrine being an issue), you could store the context for a short time and check for it when the javascript request comes in.